# Не запускается только что скачанный QTCreator 5.5.1 для linux x86

Tags: linux, qtcreator

При старте из консоли пишет:

> QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
>   QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete, missing draw buffer.
>   QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete, missing draw buffer.
>   QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
>   QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete, missing draw buffer.
>   QOpenGLShader: could not create shader QOpenGLShader: could not create
>   shader Ошибка сегментирования

`mesa-utils` установлено

**Система:** `Mint Rosa 17.3 x86`

как быть ?

Comment: наверно, надо не из консоли запускать, а из «иксового» эмулятора терминала. *x-сервер* у вас вообще запущен?

Comment: ошибка терминологии. запускал как раз из эмулятора теринала - увидеть что не так, так как при запуске из меню DE не происходит ничего

Comment: 1. сборку-то 32-битную скачали? (сужу по упоминанию вами слова `x86`, что должно подразумевать 32-битную архитектуру intel). 2. проприетарщина какая-нибудь стоит, связанная с *x-сервером*?